# What are m2e connectors?

Tags: maven, m2e

I want to know what an m2e connector is. I didn't find much on the internet describing them except this page:

http://objectledge.org/confluence/display/TOOLS/M2E+Connectors

So my questions are:

- Is it a plugin like any Eclipse plugin?
- What it can be used for?
- Are there any pages explaining how I can use it?

Comment: m2e stands for maven to eclipse plugin. when you install maven plugin in eclipse. It asks for connectors to install

Comment: Making maven build more effective

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is an eclipse plugin.
It act as a bridge between one maven plugin and eclipse.
Basically it is used for three things:

- configure eclipse project according to the pom configuration,
- automatically refresh resources modify by your build,
- provide incremental build (if done correctly...)

For the common plugins,you would install it when importing maven projects, or via quick fixes.

[Some documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html), though it is more oriented to m2e connectors' development.

Comment: I am unable to import a maven project from a public git repository in bitbucket. There are no choices for scm in the import project from maven scm option. Do I need to install a m2e connector to bitbucket ?